# Will I fail timed Levemetes if I log out?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

All the Levemetes I've done so far have been timed. If I log out, does that timer continue to run, or does it pause?

Answer (score 1):

The timer continues to run and you fill fail, and lose the leves.

Answer (score 1):

Having been disconnected and logging back in well before the timer should have been up (15 minutes when d/c'd, back in-game within 5 minutes), I can tell you from experience that any kind of disconnect from the server, be it voluntary or otherwise, will cause you to fail any ongoing levequest.

Of course, you can use one of your Allowances to re-challenge it.